# How to mix pure CO2 with air so that a bioreactor can be fed with air at 0.1% to 10% CO2?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, airflow, process-engineering, prototyping

The situation is we have to prepare a gas mix of air and CO<sub>2</sub> which has to be given as input from 0.1% to 10% CO<sub>2</sub> of air mix to the aqueous medium in a bioreactor?

I'm trying to build a simple and cheap DIY bioreactor. So how do we mix pure CO<sub>2</sub> from a CO<sub>2</sub> canister with air from a compressor or from a compressed air cylinder at the right flow rates so that we can achieve a desired air mix with CO<sub>2</sub> supplied at 1 LPM to 30 LPM?

***More particularly, what is the cheapest and best volumetric or mass flow meters and CO<sub>2</sub> detectors that can be sourced and put together for this purpose? Also, what are the parameters to consider for gas mixing calculation?***

The need is to have a satisfactory and approximate accuracy in terms of gas mixing and CO<sub>2</sub> detection. I have also added a simple diagram of this gas mixing system for reference.

[image: Gas mixing]

It'd be great to get help from the community. Please do suggest if any other possible ways exist as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the sensors used on car exhaust systems? Or even the car gas exhaust analysers?

Comment: Didnt think about it. Was mostly looking into off-the-shelf CO2 sensors like from Adafruit that uses IR to measure CO2 in ppm. That gives fairly accurate result. It is comparatively cheaper than gas analyzers.

Comment: Remember that cheap is not likely to be "best" but do define "best"...

Comment: Valid point, Mike. Thanks for being prompt. Digital sensors or analyzers with an accuracy of 0.1% in CO2 concentration measurement at <$100-200 is what I'm looking for.

Comment: do you need online, digital control, or do analog flow meters and manual ontrol of valves suffice?

Comment: Analog flow meters and manual control of valves will suffice my case. Would love to learn and consider real time digital controls as well. Not keen about complete online and full process automation.

Comment: and do you need to control the precise amount going into the tank?

Comment: Yes but not looking at ultimate precision.

Comment: The tricky part will be the 0.1 - 10% range, with a smaller range it would be easy to build somthing with manual control valves and rotameters. I'll sleep on it, we'll see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127805/discussion-between-giri-and-mart).

Comment: If asking these questions, and need within ~1%, just buy mass flow controller for each gas in the mixture. It won't be super cheap. Be sure to pick the full scale range per reach mixture component. Control of P,T upstream will always help..... If shoestring budget but skilled person, constructing a differential pressure flow meter using capillary tube and cheap digital differential pressure sensor (e.g. Honeywell HSCD) is possible - must be calibrated e.g. with inverted graduated cylinder underwater. Must have everything at known temp. Manual ctrl w/ needle valves e.g. SMC

Comment: adafruit.com 4867 (CO2 sensor). I used an arduino.cc UNO board, humidity sensor, PID controller (library add-on for arduino using their programming system from arduino.cc) to create air with a programmable humidity. Have a large volume box maybe with a stirr fan inside. As air is brought in inject using PID to control CO2 % and pump this into your biomass.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I was able to learn the some great points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways.  To cut cost, reduce your expensive sensors to a bare minimum - probably just measuring what goes into the reactor.

Controlling by mass tends to be expensive compared to by volume or pressure.  Ideal gas law is your friend here.  Pressure times volume is proportional to number of particles times temperature.  It's pretty inexpensive to bring two gasses to the same temperature, especially if you let them mix, but even if you just have their lines adjacent, they'll get there with enough time at sufficiently low flow.

In your diagram, if you theoretically just have valves instead of the mass flow meters, you could adjust them until you reach the desired output and then connect the reactor, wasting some gasses initially.  From then, you would only adjust one valve at a time carefully and slowly bringing the setup closer to a target condition.

There's a more interesting method involving the ideal gas law I mentioned.  You start with a "tank" of air (~.036% CO<sub>2</sub> by volume) of known volume and pressure.  You add CO<sub>2</sub> from the cylinder until it reaches the percentage you want.  By the ideal gas law (approximation), you can detect when you reach this desired percentage by measuring the temperature (pretty inexpensive) and pressure (need control that anyway)!  You can control it with a pressure regulator like one for pumping tires.  Final step is to dump this formulated mix to a desired location.  This is where the "tank" being a pneumatic actuator instead helps - just pressurize the other chamber and move the mix onward either to the reactor (cheap) or a holding tank (you should just use it as the "tank" if that's the case, and add air or CO<sub>2</sub> based on the sensor).  At the extra cost of more check valves, you can even use that other chamber as the start of the next mix (probably cheap enough to toss it though).  With a programmable controller in charge of it all, you can have it adjust the target pressures on the fly based on the CO<sub>2</sub> sensor reading from the previous mix.

Should make for a good diy (or high school science lab) project.

Comment: Thank you Abel. Indeed, the ideal gas equation is the savior here.